# How to avoid evicting entries from Guava Cache

Tags: java, caching, guava

I'm using Guava `Cache` to cache about 100K records in memory. I use `cache.putAll(Map<K,V>)` to pre-load the cache. After loading about 20K records, I see removal notifications with cause 'REPLACED'. Max size is 1GB and weigher returns 1 for all entries, expireAfterAccess is 24 hours. 1GB is enough for all records. How can I ensure that no entry is replaced before 24 hrs ?

```
MyCacheLoader cacheLoader = new MyCacheLoader();
CacheBuilder<Long, Map<String, List<String>>> cacheBuilder = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().
        initialCapacity(1024 * 1024 * 1024).
        //maximumSize(1024 * 1024 * 1024).
        maximumWeight(1000000).
        weigher(new Weigher<Long, Map<String, List<String>>>(){
            public int weigh(Long arg0, Map<String, List<String>> arg1) {
                return 1;
            }
        }).
        concurrencyLevel(1).
        expireAfterAccess(24, TimeUnit.HOURS);

cache = cacheBuilder.build(cacheLoader);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is that you might be adding duplicate keys.

**UPDATE**

From JavaDocs for [`RemovalCause.REPLACED`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/RemovalCause.html#REPLACED):

> The entry itself was not actually removed, but its value was replaced by the user. This can result from the user invoking Cache.put(K, V), LoadingCache.refresh(K), Map.put(K, V), Map.putAll(java.util.Map), ConcurrentMap.replace(Object, Object), or ConcurrentMap.replace(Object, Object, Object).

So since it's not a `LoadingCache`, judging by a doc, this leaves only two possibilities: a duplicate or a bug.

---

From the source of `LocalCache`, zero weight means non-evictable objects:

```
ReferenceEntry<K, V> getNextEvictable() {
  for (ReferenceEntry<K, V> e : accessQueue) {
    int weight = e.getValueReference().getWeight();
    if (weight > 0) {
      return e;
    }
  }
  throw new AssertionError();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrey, just changed the weight to 1, still seeing the same behavior.

Comment: Hey, my answer says that the problem is not with the weigher, it might be duplicate keys you are adding.

Comment: Ok, went back and verified, the ones being replaced are unique keys, no duplicates found.

Comment: You are right, there are a few duplicate keys, that trigger removal/replacement. Fixed those and the problem is gone! Thanks a ton!!

Comment: I've added a link to JavaDoc if this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I do not use weigher very often, but I believe when you use a weight of 0, that can cause your values to be evicted.

Also, note that the documentation says not to use weight in conjuction with maximumSize.

From [CacheBuilder.html#maximumWeight](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/16.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#maximumWeight(long))

> When weight is zero, elements will be evicted immediately after being
>   loaded into cache. This can be useful in testing, or to disable
>   caching temporarily without a code change.
>
> Note that weight is only used to determine whether the cache is over
>   capacity; it has no effect on selecting which entry should be evicted
>   next.
>
> This feature cannot be used in conjunction with maximumSize.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Changed the weigher to return 1 and removed maxSize, but no change :(